# SC_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED(225) with Suricata on CentOS 6.5

Tags: security

I have just installed installed Suricata 2.0.3 RELEASE on CentOS 6.5.  I try running it with

```
sudo suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i eth0
```

and get the following warning

```
<Warning> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED(225)] - Eve-log support not compiled in. Reconfigure/recompile with libjansson and its development files installed to add eve-log support.
```

I compilied and install Jannson as outlined [here](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/gettingstarted.html) and then rebuilt Suricata as follows.

```
sudo make
sudo make-install
sudo make-install-full
```

and everything proceeded without any errors.  However I still get the SC_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED warning.  I did a search for the error message and found [a link](https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/issues/1205) that said it was a known issue that won't be fixed due to an issue with the Jannson library.  Is this the case?  If so, can I disable this warning?

Comment: The libjansson version you used is likely too old. The doc link suggests you used 1.1. Please try 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue on my Ubuntu box, here's what I did to get rid of it.

1. Go install the libjansson 2.7 library.  You can find it [here](http://www.digip.org/jansson/).
2. Run these commands to recompile with the new libjansson library.

   ```
   ./configure <whatever flags you had before> --with-libjansson libraries=/path/to/lib/dir --with-libjansson-includes=/path/to/include/dir
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
3. Run suricata to make sure the warning went away.

   ```
   sudo suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i <interface>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem in CentOS 7.

Install package:

```
yum install jansson
```

Then I ran configure script as below :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ --localstatedir=/var/ --with-libjansson-libraries=/usr/lib64 --with-libjansson-includes=/usr/include <some other flags>
```

I am using 64-bit machine that's why it's /usr/lib64, otherwise it should be /usr/lib.

Compile the codes:

```
make
make install-full
```

Run suricata:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib /usr/bin/suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i eth0
```

eth0 is interface (device) name here.